# How to check if gradient descent with multiple variables converged correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

In linear regression with 1 variable I can clearly see on plot prediction line and I can see if it properly fits the training data. I just create a plot with 1 variable and output and construct prediction line based on found values of Theta 0 and Theta 1. So, it looks like this:
[image]

---

But how can I check validity of gradient descent results implemented on multiple variables/features. For example, if number of features is 4 or 5. How to check if it works correctly and found values of all thetas are valid? Do I have to rely only on cost function plotted against number of iterations carried out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradient descent converges to a local minimum, meaning that the first derivative should be zero and the second non-positive. Checking these two matrices will tell you if the algorithm has converged.

Comment: it is worth noting, that derivative is rarely zero in practise (like any other value - achieving any particular value has nearly zero probability in continuous functions), furthermore, in fintie precision arithmetics "zero" is quite weird term. Usually one uses approximations such as assuming that 10e-20 is zero, which **does not mean that it converged**, it only means that "surface of error is so flat, our arithmetic fails to go further"

Comment: First derivate of what should be zero?

Comment: @kikatuso I mean the first derivative of the function that gradient descent is being performed on.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of gradient descent as of something solving a problem of `f'(x) = 0` where `f'` denotes gradient of `f`. For checking this problem convergence, as far as I know, the standard approach is to calculate discrepancy on each iteration and see if it converges to 0.
That is, check if `||f'(x)||` (or its square) converges to 0.

Comment: this answer is a subset of Don Reba's answer

Comment: @lejlot, disagree. I understood Don Reba's answer (and your comment) as an advice on strictly comparing derivative to zero

Comment: there is no such thing as "check if congerges to zero", there is no way to check it in other way then: comparing if value is small (see his answer) or checking if it "does not change much" which is equivalent to checking gradient of gradient, thus - second derivative (again - exactly what he suggests in the second part).

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can try.

1) Check if your cost/energy function is not improving as your iteration progresses. Use something like "abs(E_after - E_before) < 0.00001*E_before", i.e. check if the relative difference is very low.

2) Check if your variables have stopped changing. You can opt a very similar strategy like above to check this.

There is actually no perfect way to fully make sure that your function has converged, but some of the things mentioned above are what usually people try.

Good luck!

Comment: What about batch gradient descent?